# I'm using angular6 and content inside the tag ng-content is not displaying when the page is loading initially

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-content

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.css']
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {

  recipe : Recipe;

  show: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  emittedRecipeItem(emittedRecipe : Recipe){
    this.recipe= emittedRecipe;
    this.show = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <app-recipe-list (selectedRecipeItem)="emittedRecipeItem($event)"></app-recipe-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <app-recipe-detail *ngIf="show; else infotext" [recipeItemDetail]="recipe">
      <ng-template #infotext>
          Please select a recipe !
      </ng-template>
    </app-recipe-detail>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to display the Please select recipe in my UI page.

I have used ng-template option but its not working as expected.

Content inside the  tag is not displaying

Comment: Can you add a stackbiltz

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-template` is nested inside your custom component with the `*ngIf`.

The structure should be:

```
 <app-recipe-detail *ngIf="show; else infotext" [recipeItemDetail]="recipe">    
 </app-recipe-detail>

 <ng-template #infotext>
   Please select a recipe!
 </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-7-install-recipe-emit)

I replaced your `app-recipe-list` with a single `button`.